# Why cant I drop a file into the Qt Sample drop example?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, drag-and-drop

I am trying to get dropping a file into the application to work and so I compiled the [example](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/draganddrop-dropsite.html) but every time I try to drop a file, I get the "not allowed to drop" symbol. I tried this also with my own example and in debug mode I find that none of the implemented functions (dragEnterEvent, dragMoveEvent, dropEvent) are even reached. What is the problem here / how do I fix this?

Also, running Qt 4.8 on Win7 x64

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the issue: you cant drag and drop from a non escalated application (explorer.exe) to an escalated one.

Thanks to @HansPassant for the workaround: add a manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
    <assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
    <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">
        <security>
            <requestedPrivileges>
                <requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="true"/>
            </requestedPrivileges>
        </security>
    </trustInfo>
</assembly>
```

This manifest requires 'uiAccess' to be true and that requires the exe to be trusted and signed.

Note: the solution proposed in http://helgeklein.com/blog/2010/03/how-to-enable-drag-and-drop-for-an-elevated-mfc-application-on-vistawindows-7/ using `ChangeWindowMessageFilter` does NOT work.